# Is it possible to have an "alias" for byte array in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to call an overloaded callback method that can accept several different types as possible arguments.

```
string s = "some text";
PerformCallback(s);

int i = 42;
PerformCallback(i);

byte[] ba = new byte[] { 4, 2 };
PerformCallback(ba);
```

So far no problem. But now I want to have two different kinds of byte arrays, let's call them blue byte arrays and green byte arrays. The byte arrays themselves are, well, just byte arrays. Their blueness and greeness is only a philosophical concept, but I'd like to write an overloaded callback method that has two different overloads for the two kinds of byte arrays, and a way of invoking the two different overloads. I'd prefer very much to avoid having to use an extra argument to indicate the color of the byte arrays, and I'd prefer to avoid anything that adds an enclosing class or similar that will add runtime overhead.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to differentiate between the two different "kinds"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could create a struct which *just* contains a byte array, and then possibly have implicit conversions to/from `byte[]`... that way you end up with separate types for the sake of overloads etc.

As it's a struct there would be no overhead in terms of memory - there may well be a *very slight* overhead involved in running the operator (or just the constructor) but it's at least *likely* that the JIT will inline everything to heck anyway. I certainly wouldn't expect it to have a significant performance impact.

(To be honest, you could make it an enclosing class and you'd still be unlikely to notice any difference unless this was being used in a tight loop, IMO. Performance bottlenecks are rarely where we expect them to be.)

Comment: @Graphain: Well, he want to avoid adding an enclosing *class* - and enclosing *struct* may be a different matter.

Comment: A `struct` containing just a reference should take up no more memory than just a reference, right? So I don't think there should be any measurable overhead.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But won't enclosing the byte array in another struct result in the creation of an extra copy of the byte array on the stack, and the time required to copy the bytes? I guess what I'm hoping for is an alternative type that is just like a byte array and works just like a byte array, but that the compiler still considers to be different enough so an additional overload of my callback method can be created.

Comment: Never mind - now I realize the byte array itself is not on the stack, only the reference to it. I'll give it a try. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, you want to distinguish between:

```
byte[] ba = new byte[] { 4, 2 };
```

and

```
byte[] ba = new byte[] { 4, 2 };
```

?

If you aren't wrapping them in a different class there is *no* way to tell them apart?
 The alternative is attributes and that would have a very real runtime penalty, unlike the expectedly small one a value class wrapper would have.

If you really wanted you could add a byte to the start indicating its colour and `if` on that in your method right?

Answer (score 0):

your blue byte arrays and green byte arrays are the same type. to avoid using extra arguments and so
it'd better to hendle them in 2 different methods.

PerformCallbackBlue(ba); and PerformCallbackGreen(ba);

Of cause you can do it even better think about the architecture and use disign patterns f.e.
get a base inferface with PerformCallback method and 2 inherited classes  for blue and green arrays.